# How to show ports on which Odoo server is in running state

Tags: ubuntu, process, terminal, odoo, kill-process

How to display all running odoo instance in my terminal, and How to forced stop all instance.

Answer (score 4):

**Display all running odoo instances:**

```
sudo ps aux | grep openerp
```

(or)

```
sudo ps aux | grep odoo
```

**Stop all running odoo instance:**

```
sudo kill -9 {id}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to show any particular process in Ubuntu using terminal so `PS` Command is used.

**Name**
ps - report a snapshot of the current processes.

**DESCRIPTION**
ps displays information about a selection of the active processes.

To see every process on the system using BSD syntax:

```
ps ax
ps axu
```

Now use show particular process from list of process so use `grep` command,

**NAME**
grep - print lines matching a pattern

**DESCRIPTION**
grep searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for lines containing a match to the given PATTERN. By default, grep prints the matching lines.

Now we are find odoo server process so use following command using `PIP` command,

```
ps -ax | grep openerp
```

**Output, i.e**
ID
9941

After kill openerp service using `Kill` command,

```
kill -9 <pid_number>
```

**i.e**
    kill -9 9941

After kill command execute to `openerp` service/server is close. And after you want to check service is start or not so again `PS` command execute to check out process is off or on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command for finding the state of odoo server

```
ps -aef|grep odoo
```

or

```
ps -aef|grep openerp
```

To kill

```
sudo kill -9 porcess_id
```